# What is the structure of a PDB file?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I am trying to understand how a debugger uses PDB file. It would probably be a small file system in itself. Could someone help me understand the structure of the PDB file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx), the actual file format is kept secret by MS. However, I recommend you read that post as it has a lot of useful information what a `PDB` file is and how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx), its impractical:

> Because the format of the .pdb file generated by the postcompiler
>   tools undergoes constant revision, exposing the format is impractical

A debugger would use the [DIA SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6tay6cz.aspx) to access the data inside them, meaning you don't really need to know its structure.

Comment: You do need to know the structure when you're a compiler writer, who wants to emit a `pdb` file with your binary.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, the format of PDB is not documented, but you can collect very detailed information about the content of PDB files programmatically using the appropriate interfaces [See Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37456/How-To-Inspect-the-Content-of-a-Program-Database-P)